# Gitlab CI and Protractor

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've been trying to figure it out for some time now, but I am unable to.

I am trying to use gitlab ci to test php and angularjs app. so far i was able to run all of the php unit tests, but keep on failing with the angularjs protractor test.

```
# Select image from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
#image: node
image: ubuntu:14.04
#image: vdubyna/gitlab-ci-docker-runner

services:
#  - java
#  - blinkmobile/bower
#  - caltha/protractor
#  - selenium/base
  - siomiz/chrome

# # Select what we should cache
cache:
   paths:
     - vendor/
     - node_modules/


before_script:


  ## Install Java
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install curl -y
  - apt-get install git -y
  - apt-get install default-jre -y

  - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
  - apt-get install -y nodejs
  - npm -g install httpster
#  - npm -g install bower
  - npm install -g protractor
#  - npm install # install npm packages
  - webdriver-manager update
#  - bower install --allow-root


job1:
  script:
    - java -version
    - httpster > ~/program.log 2>&1 &
    - protractor test/protractor.conf.js
```

where I am stuck now, is that it's unable to run the test because I don't have chrome installed...

Comment: Where is the runner hosted? Is it the shared runner from GitLab or your own?

Comment: @JoseTorres I got it on google compute cloud (running it from docker), I've also tried the shared ones.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested with Protractor but when the Runners available are missing a dependency I turn to a local setup considering I'm already able to run everything on my dev machine. Take into consideration that Runners are the ones that require these libraries and services to build your project not the GitLab server itself. Later on you can build a public runner for your team.

To do this use the docs here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner#installation. The instructions basically guide you through downloading the code, changing permissions, registering the runners and starting/stopping it. Installation is available different operating systems. Just remember that when your registering a runner all the information it requires is on your GitLab application under project/runners.

Hope this helps.